# How to do a bidirectional link for Slider and SpinBox controls?

Tags: python, user-interface, slider, blackmagic-fusion

I'm trying to link two common controls in the GUI, a Slider and a SpinBox. They are from a Python library for the `Blackmagic Fusion` software. It happen that in the way that I'm trying it seems are overriding the Slider control with SpinBox value.

Here the available events for these two items

**Slider**:
ValueChanged, 
SliderMoved, 
ActionTriggered, 
SliderPressed, 
SliderRelease, 
RangeChanged,

**SpinBox**:
EditingFinished, 
ValueChanged

```
 # GUI 
 dlg = disp.AddWindow({'ID': 'myWin', 'WindowTitle': 'myWin', 'Geometry': [ 400, 100, 230, 400 ],},
 [  
     ui.Slider({ 'ID': 'mySlider', 'Events': { 'SliderMoved': True, 'Activated': True } }),
     ui.SpinBox({ 'ID': 'mySpinBox' }),
 ])

 itm = dlg.GetItems()

 # Updates the Spin value when moves the Slider
 def _func(ev):
     var = ev['Value']
     itm['mySpinBox'].Value = var
 dlg.On.mySlider.SliderMoved = _func

 # Updates thed Slider position when SpinBox value is changed
 def _func(ev):
     itm['mySlider'].Value = itm['mySpinBox'].Value 
 dlg.On.mySpinBox.ValueChanged = _func
```